# How do I make Emacs not complain about not being able to start a new server?

Tags: emacsclient, server, warning, popup, org-protocol

I use the mac port version of emacs for handling org-protocol URLs, because I need a graphical instance when I use org-protocol from Chrome. The problem is that emacs will try to start an emacs server whenever it receives these org-protocol requests, but I already have an emacs server running using a terminal-instance emacs. I can't just let the graphical instance be the server, as that makes me unable to use emacsclient from the terminal with the error `*ERROR*: Not using an ASCII terminal now; cannot make a new ASCII frame`.

Everything works fine though, if I just ignore the warning about the server:
[image]

So is there any way to get rid of that popup?

Comment: Why do you need a graphical instance at all? All that the browser should be doing is call `emacsclient` with the appropriate arguments and that should connect to the already running emacs server.

Comment: @NickD The graphical instance gets the focus from Chrome, and lets me edit the capture; The terminal one can't bring iTerm into the focus (or at least not without some code on my part).

Comment: Is the graphical emacs brought up as a response to the org-protocol request and is then shut down or does it run "for ever"? What is the emacsclient invocation of the org-protocol request?  If it runs "for ever", you may want to configure a [TCP Emacs server](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/TCP-Emacs-server.html#TCP-Emacs-server) that listens to a different port than your terminal emacs server (if that is a TCP server too - it may be using local sockets instead - unless you are on Windoze).

Comment: @NickD The graphical instance is always open on my desktop (if it is not, it'll start and then lives "for ever"). There is no emacsclient invocation when the graphical instance is set as the handler of org-protocol URL schemes, as it handles them natively (a feature of the mac port version). I can change the handler to any custom command though, and your suggestion of using two different servers seem reasonable to me. Thanks.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure how the communication is set up: with emacsclient you'd have to use the `-f` option to tell it where the server is listening; but without emacsclient, you'll have to figure out who does the communicating before you can tell them the same information. Hope you figure it out (and if you do, be sure to provide an answer)!